# Jenkins - Store code previous version number, and take actions if version number changes

Tags: python, git, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins with python code as follows.

After detecting a change to the GIT dev branch:

- Checkout GIT repository dev branch code
- Perform Unit tests / code coverage
- If build passes, check code into the production branch of the same repo

What I want to add, is the ability to keep track of the previous code version (the python code package stores the version number in the setup.py file ) and if the version in the latest build job is incremented compared to the saved version, only then check the passed code into the production branch.

Any thoughts on how best to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Playing around with this, I am able to fail a build if the version number is not incremented, but I can't see a way to pass the build but just block the git publish if the version isn't incremented.

Answer (score 0):

I've made use of the following plugins to achieve this:

- [Flexible Publish Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/flexible-publish/)
- [Run Condition Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/run-condition/)